# Is there a prime between $k$ and $\dfrac{11}{9}k$, $\forall k\ge 24$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Given $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $k\ge 24$, is there always a prime number in the interval $\left[k,\dfrac{11}{9}k\right]$?
I tried to verify this statement with the computer and it seems to hold. Is it possible to prove it?

Comment: Prime number theorem essentially states that there is always a prime between $p_n$ and $(1+\varepsilon) p_n$.

Comment: You can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) some results in this direction. It was proven by Nagura in 1952 that for all $n \ge 25$ there is a prime between $n$ and $\frac 65 n$.

Comment: @martini: Thanks

Comment: @BalarkaSen Only for $n$ large enough and without being specific about "large enough"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various results the give absolute upper bounds on $\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}$, converging to $1$ and holding for sufficiently large $n$. See, for example, those by Dussart mentioned at [Prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Bounds_on_the_prime-counting_function) and [Bertrand's postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate#Better_results) at Wikipedia.

Thanks to these results, every true statement of the general form you give is provable -- the general result gives an $n$ beyond which it is *guaranteed* to be true, and if your limit is smaller than that, there's a finite number of cases to check.